# Get Employee ID from People picker from InfoPath Form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have a form where I have three fields:

**Submitter Employee ID** - Single line text box

**Recipient** - People Picker which captures multiple users

**Recipient Employee ID's** - Multiline text box

I am able to capture Submitter's Employee ID by using userName() function on **Submitter Employee ID** field.

I am able to capture Recipient's Employee ID when only one Recipient is selected from **Recipient** field.

But,
When the submitter selects multiple users from the **Recipient**'s people picker, I want the selected user's Employee ID's in **Recipient Employee ID's** field.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple user's Employee ID from Recipient people picker in Recipient Employee ID field,set the default value of Recipient Employee ID field as the following:

eval(eval(AccountId, 'concat(., ";")'), "..")

[image]

Reference:

http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2013/videos/merge-people-picker-infopath-2013.htm